# Applying for Schengen visa from UK

Tags: uk, schengen

My mother is visiting me from Sri Lanka (I’m in the UK ) with a visitor visa valid for 6 months form Mid Aug to Mid Feb 2017. We wanted take her to Schengen countries in December 2018 and we know usually we can’t apply for a schengen visa from UK for those hold visitor visa. Therefore we applied for a schengen visa in Sri Lanka giving travel dates in October once and again in December. She got the visa for October (only for 10 days) and there is no visa for December. Her children around the world are going to go to Swiss in December for a family holiday and we want her to be with us. I’m at a lost how we can get her a schengen visa for December.

We can’t apply from Sri Lanka as she would be leaving to UK in August and we can’t apply from there (Sri Lanka) before three months. We can’t usually apply from UK. Is there anyone who know how to handle this situation?

Comment: What response did you receive on the December application?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mother should write an e-mail to the consulate of one of the Schengen countries located in Sri Lanka, where your mother should apply for a visa if she would not leave to the UK, describe them the situation in detail and ask for the permission to apply for a Schengen visa from the UK.

I, a citizen of the Russian Federation, had the same situation when applied for a Schengen visa (Germany) from Brazil where I was as a tourist together with my husband who had an internship in Brazil. We were in Brazil for quite a while, so I was not able to apply for a Schengen visa from Russia. I wrote to our local German consulate, described the situation, asked for permission to apply for a visa from Brazil, got it, applied for a visa from Brazil, and successfully got a visa.